# Latex table goes out of the page border

Tags: tables, margins, page, border

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{User-Story ID: 01}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} 
\hline
\textbf{User-Story ID:} & 01                   \\
\hline
\textbf{Title:} & Physician Registration                  \\
\hline
\textbf{Actor:} & Physician                   \\
\hline
\textbf{Priority} & 01                   \\
\hline
\textbf{Estimate} & not written yet  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{User Story:} As a physician, I want an interface 
from where I can register myself in the website by giving my details, so that 
I can have access to the different functionalities of physicians. The 
interface should be easily understandable and shows all requirements needed 
for registration}    \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Acceptance Criteria:}}    \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: https://ibb.co/cNgHwjC]

I am trying to adjust the table but don't know how to do it.

Comment: `l` columns does not support automatic line breaking. You might want to look at `p{length} ` instead. This does support line breaking.

Comment: A `l` type columns, such as the one you used for "User Story" will print all of its contents in a single line. If you want a cell with fixed width and automatic linebreaks, use something like `\multicolumn{2}{|p{7cm}|}{\textbf{User Story:}....}` instead. Of course you can adjust the width to suit your needs. `\multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{\textbf{User Story:} ...}` will result in a table that is exactly as wide as the textwidth.

Comment: Unrelated, it is generally not a good idea to only use `[h] `, use at least `[htp] ` in order to have the float placed as close as possible. You should probably also use the caption package  and instruct it that table captions are at the top to get better spacing between the caption and the table

Comment: Thank You guys. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, set the overall width of the `tabularx` environment to `\textwidth`, and employ the `X` column type for the right-hand column to allow automatic line-breaking; LaTeX will calculate the column width of the 2nd column for you -- no need for any manual calculations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-craped "look"
\caption{User-Story ID: 01\strut}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|L|} 
\hline
\textbf{User-Story ID} & 01  \\
\hline
\textbf{Title} & Physician Registration \\
\hline
\textbf{Actor} & Physician \\
\hline
\textbf{Priority} & 01 \\
\hline
\textbf{Estimate} & not written yet \\
\hline
\textbf{User Story} & As a physician, I want an interface from where 
I can register myself in the website by giving my details, so that I 
can have access to the different functionalities of physicians. The  
interface should be easily understandable and show all requirements 
needed for registration. \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Acceptance Criteria}:} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to keep the `\multicolumn`-based approach, you could use one of the following two suggestions in order to get a table that is as wide as the textwidth:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{User-Story ID: 01}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} 
\hline
\textbf{User-Story ID:} & 01                   \\
\hline
\textbf{Title:} & Physician Registration                  \\
\hline
\textbf{Actor:} & Physician                   \\
\hline
\textbf{Priority} & 01                   \\
\hline
\textbf{Estimate} & not written yet  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{\textbf{User Story:} As a physician, I want an interface 
from where I can register myself in the website by giving my details, so that 
I can have access to the different functionalities of physicians. The 
interface should be easily understandable and shows all requirements needed 
for registration}    \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Acceptance Criteria:}}    \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\caption{User-Story ID: 01}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} 
\hline
\textbf{User-Story ID:} & 01                   \\
\hline
\textbf{Title:} & Physician Registration                  \\
\hline
\textbf{Actor:} & Physician                   \\
\hline
\textbf{Priority} & 01                   \\
\hline
\textbf{Estimate} & not written yet  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\hangindent=10pt}|}{\textbf{User Story:} As a physician, I want an interface 
from where I can register myself in the website by giving my details, so that 
I can have access to the different functionalities of physicians. The 
interface should be easily understandable and shows all requirements needed 
for registration}    \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Acceptance Criteria:}}    \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed here, hope it helps.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{User-Story ID: 01}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
\hline
\textbf{User-Story ID:} & 01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \hline
\textbf{Title:}         & Physician Registration                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\ \hline
\textbf{Actor:}         & Physician                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
\textbf{Priority}       & 01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \hline
\textbf{Estimate}       & not written yet                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
\textbf{User Story:}    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
As a physician, I want an interface\\ from where I can register myself 
in the website by giving my details, \\ so that  I can have access to the 
different functionalities of physicians. \\ The interface should be 
easily understandable \\ and shows all requirements needed for 
registration
\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Acceptance Criteria:}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, Problem solved.

Comment: don't forget voting and marking my answer as useful.

Comment: @Bpi I have marked, instead, your answer positive :-)

Comment: Two downsides of this approach is that it requires manual insertion of line breaks and that there's no guarantee that the table will fit within the text block. In fact, assuming that default margin settings are in effect, the table shown above will protrude noticeably into the right-hand margin.